# Open div in current clicked TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr><td class="click" id="111">111</td> <td id="222" class="click">222</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="click" id="333">333</td> <td id="444" class="click">444</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="hidden">
   text
</div>

#tab tr td {
padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

#hidden {
    background-color:green;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: none;
}

$(".click").click(function(){
    $("#hidden").show();
})
```

How to open div #hidden in current clicked TD? and if i click outside #hidden i would like hide this div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QyRnH/2/

Comment: see now http://jsfiddle.net/QyRnH/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "How to open div #hidden in current clicked TD", but to show and hide the `#hidden` div you could do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QyRnH/7/

```
<table id="tab">
  <tr>
    <td class="click" id="111">1</td> 
    <td class="click" id="222">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="click" id="333">3</td> 
    <td class="click" id="444">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="hidden">text</div>

$(".click").click(function(e){
   $("#hidden").show();
   $("#hidden").appendTo($(this));
   e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
   $('#hidden').hide();
});
```

Comment: if i click on 111 then i want these div in TD 111

Answer (score 3):

Try something like below

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    $("#hidden").show();
    $("#hidden").offset($(this).offset());

});
```

To change left and top you can write something like

```
$("#hidden").offset({top: $(this).offset().top, left: $(this).offset().left+10});
```

To hide the div when clicked outside, please refer the answer posted by Krister Andersson

Comment: thanks, is possible manipulate this? left and top? and how can i hide div if i click outsite DIV?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/QyRnH/6/

HTML:

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td class="click" id="111">
        111
            <div class="hidden">
               text
            </div>
        </td> 
        <td id="222" class="click">
            222
            <div class="hidden">
               text
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="click" id="333">
            333
            <div class="hidden">
               text
            </div>
        </td> 
        <td id="444" class="click">
            444
            <div class="hidden">
               text
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(".click").click(function() {

    $(".hidden").hide();
    $(".hidden", this).toggle();

});
```

Comment: i would like hide div if i click outside, not toggle, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    $("#hidden").show();
    $(this).append($("#hidden"));
})
```